# How to configure PHP-FPM over NGINX to write in per-virtualhost log files

Tags: linux, nginx, logging, php-fpm

I have Fedora 16 with Nginx and PHP-FPM. Everything is working very good. All logs with PHP notices, warnings, errors etc. are in `/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`.

Is there a way to configure PHP-FPM to write errors in proper log files configured as error logs for Nginx? So I want to log PHP errors *per-virtualhost* and not in one global file. (like in Apache Httpd and PHP).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The PHP-FPM directive: `catch_workers_output = yes`
will cause errors PHP sends to stdout/stderr to be sent back to nginx, and they will be logged.

In PHP 5.2.4 and newer, the directive [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is no longer a boolean, but will accept 'stderr' as an option. This should cause all of the errors to go back to nginx, and be logged per vhost.

So in your PHP-FPM config:

`php_admin_value[display_errors] = 'stderr'`

Your other option is the directive:

`php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log`

which is what you are likely using now. the php-fpm.conf supports some variables, like $pool (which for you, will likely return 'www').

If you have more than 1 pool, you can easily log them separately.

From a quick browse through the source code, it looks like $pool is the only such variable though.

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be [some issue with `display_errors="stderr"`](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3326#issuecomment-126506134). Have you tested it to work?